# How can I list folder names that are added into lsp-workspace?

Tags: lsp

I am able to add my repo into `lsp-workspace` using: `lsp-workspace-folders-add`.

When I open a file, if its root repo is located in the `lsp-workspace`, in the minibuffer I see following message:

```
LSP :: pylsp:289202 initialized successfully in folders: (/home/alper/project/repo)
```

---

Even I do `lsp-workspace-folders-add` sometimes the lsp is not applied into the repo. When the folder's path is changed it works though.

I was wondering is it possible to list all the folders that are already added into `lsp-workspace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run `M-x lsp-workspace-folders-open`